# How to add 'per person' to a category price in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

Using woocommerce, I have several categories but would like to add "per person" to the category "cookery classes".
I have written this function, which works on all products.
I can't seem to get it to work only on the category.

```
'/*---------Adds per person to price -------*/
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_price_html', 500, 2 );
function custom_price_html( $price, $product ) {
if (( int ) is_category( 'Cookery Classes','product_cat', $product->id ) )
$price .='per person';
$price .= '<span class="from"><BR>' . _x('per person', 'price_per_person','woocommerce') . ' </span>';
return $price;
}'
```

Comment: I have used a plugin called Custom Price Label to resolve this: https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-custom-price-label/ Still curious on a solution though please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found and installed this plugin:
`https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-jetpack/`
Allows you to add custom labels to prices per product catagory